# How to place an else funtion in this code?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to not show the text Color or Length etc if fields are empty?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'acf_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );

function acf_template_loop_product_meta() {

    echo '<h4>Color:' . get_field( '$colors = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_colors' )' .'</h4>';
    echo '<h4>Length:' . get_field( 'length' ) . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>Petal Count:' . get_field( 'petal_count' ) . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>Bud Size:' . get_field( 'bud_size' ) . '</h4>';
}

else {}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to show what you have tried and what results/errors you received. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the help center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't make it easier and have readibility:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'acf_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );

function acf_template_loop_product_meta() {

    if($colors = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_colors' ) && get_field( $colors )){
        echo '<h4>Color:' . get_field( $colors ) . '</h4>';
    }

    if( get_field( 'length' ) ){
        echo '<h4>Length:' . get_field( 'length' ) . '</h4>';
    }

    echo '<h4>Petal Count:' . get_field( 'petal_count' ) . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>Bud Size:' . get_field( 'bud_size' ) . '</h4>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return early before echoing the `h4` elements if the fields are missing.

The `$product->get_attribute('pa_colors')` line won't work however, as the `$product` variable isn't defined. Maybe you are missing a `global $product;` in the function?

```php
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'acf_template_loop_product_meta', 20);

function acf_template_loop_product_meta()
{
    $colors = $product->get_attribute('pa_colors');

    if (!get_field('length') || !get_field('petal_count') || !get_field('bud_size')) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<h4>Color:' . get_field($colors) . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>Length:' . get_field('length') . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>Petal Count:' . get_field('petal_count') . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>Bud Size:' . get_field('bud_size') . '</h4>';
}
```